# Cleanest way of fitting an integer in a range

Tags: ruby

What's the cleanest way of fitting an integer in a given range in ruby? A method that returns the given range's min or max if the integer it's invoked on exceeds the range.

Does a method like this exist in native ruby?

```
120.fit(1..100) # => 100
-20.fit(1..100) # => 1
```

Or maybe there's a nice one liner that does the same?

**Edit**

To achieve this I now have to do something like:

```
some_integer = some_range.min if some_integer <= some_range.min
some_integer = some_range.max if some_integer >= some_range.max
```

Comment: what you want not clear?

Comment: no, there isn't. but it looks easy enough to write it...

Comment: From that link, I quite like `(some_range.minmax << some_integer).sort[1]` although it's not very readable.

Comment: My question is indeed a duplicate and can be closed

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
class Fixnum
  def fit(range)
    self > range.max ? range.max : (self < range.min ? range.min : self)
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
> 5.fit(1..4) #=> 4
> 0.fit(1..4) #=> 1
> 3.fit(1..4) #=> 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Not confident of being cleanest, but this is a way

```
(1..100).minmax.push( -50 ).sort[1]
# => 1
(1..100).minmax.push( 120 ).sort[1]
# => 100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
r = (1..100)
v = -12
r.include?(v) ? v : ( r.begin > v ? r.begin : r.last)
```